# batch rename pdfs with the first few lines of text inside the pdf

Tags: sorting, pdf, ocr, batch-processing

I have thousands of pdfs which are basically Purchase Orders from vendors with titles like 20130121.00005.pdf. Since there are more than one Purchase Order in the folder from the same company, I want to group the files based on Vendors. The pdfs are OCRed so I was thinking if I could extract the first few lines of the pdf and use that text to rename the pdfs, I would be able to group the pdfs based on title alone. Is this possible with a simple script or something similar? I am not much of a developer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Open a few of the files up in a simple edit program like notepad and see if you can see the text you want to rename the files to the the vendor name you want the files organized into. If you can see the data, the task should be easy. I'd probably choose C and allow a folder of files to be dropped on an icon, but other languages would be as easy. Each file would be opened, a few lines read, the file closed and a system call to make the directory and move the file. Strange files would not be moved. The key is if the .pdf has the data in a readable format,

Comment: Checked format. The first few lines are as follows but the content is not in a text readable format:"%PDF-1.6
%ñù÷ö
%3.4
6 0 obj
<</BitsPerComponent 1/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Filter/JBIG2Decode/Height 3300/Length 8031/Name/ImagePart_30/Subtype/Image/Type/XObject/Width 2552>>
stream" and then binaries.

Comment: the .pdf would need to be either uncompressed or interpreted to convert the binary into text. Once the text is available, the original file would be renamed and moved and the uncompressed or interpreted file deleted, then the next file would be opened, processed and moved. [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can uncompress the file or [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) can interpret the file. pfdtk is easier to deal with. Use pdftk to decompress a .pdf and again look for the text you need, if you still don't see it, you may need ghostscript.